# Clear preference item values

Tags: android, preferences

I'm creating a PreferencesActivity where I have 3 preference items. When I click on each of them, I load contacts to pick one. After selecting a contact, I save it's name and phone number and I show it in the preference item.

But now I have to add the option to delete a contact. This would be done deleting the content of the preference, this is, clearing the strings. But my real question is, how to do this?

As there is not a normal layout, I cannot add a element for deleting that data, nor I can't do a long click on it to provide this option.

So my question is, working with preferences, what would be the way to provide the user at UI level the option to delete data from selected preference?

PD: I'm not asking about how to clear preferences data, but how to provide the user a option to clear selected preference data in the user interface (button, long click, etc...).

**preferences.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/contact">

        <Preference 
            android:key="Contact1"
            android:title="Contact 1"/>

        <Preference 
            android:key="Contact2"
            android:title="Contact 2"/>

        <Preference 
            android:key="Contact3"
            android:title="Contact 3"/>    
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score -1):

SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

```
 pref.edit().clear().commit(); //remove all your prefs :)
```

if you want to clear a specific data..then do it with the given key
eg. if you are saving a  password of the user..and on click of logout button you want to clear it.just do this way

```
 pref.edit().putString("password","").commit();
```

if you want to remove it then

```
 pref.edit().remove("password").commit();
```

Comment: Think your ar not a programmer, you are a user of this app. You start the app and you have a preferencescreen where you have 3 empty preferences. When you click on one, you get into the contacts, you selct one, and this contact name and phone now appears on the preference. Now, you want to delete this contat-preference, but remember, you are the user, not the programmer. How would you do it?

Comment: i will place a button next to each preference on screen named clear..and on the click of that button i will clear those preferences and will update the UI..to enable user to add another preference at the same place..

Comment: Ok, but how do you add that button next to each preference, lets say, at the right side? This preferences.xml file does not have the graphic layout visor as normal layouts have

Comment: i believe you are showing preferences using UI elements...if you are not..then you are making things compex..

Comment: I'm doing it the way I have posted code above. Is first time I'm working with preferences screen and I have followed some tutorials so I don't know if there is other better way to do it